# Dynamically Generate an YAML File using snakeyaml

Tags: java, spring, yaml, snakeyaml

I want to generate an YAML file which is dynamic in nature. Trying to create YAML on the fly based on the data.

Here is very simplified version of my YAML file:

```
Parent
  child1:
    - type: sampletype
      name: samplename
      desc: sampledesc
    - type: sampletype2
      name: samplename2, samplename23
      desc: sampledesc
    - type: sampletype3
      name: samplename3, samplename34
      desc: sampledesc
  child2:
    - language-type: java
    //elements are dynamic in nature for each language type
      plugins: maven
      dependencies: x,y,z
        messaging:
          type: kafka
            consumer: xyz consumer
            producer: xyz producer
```

I was thinking to create a java object and populate the fields and generate YAML using snakeyaml.

Any ideas on how to generate dynamic yaml?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by *dynamic*. Any file you create at runtime depending on runtime values is „dynamic“. Also you already give the solution: Create a Java object, populate it with your data, and then dump it with SnakeYAML. So… what is your question?

Comment: Thank you. may be i didn't articulate my question well. How do I inject different objects into Child2? I was thinking about doing private T child2; and depending on the values, construct child2.

Comment: That should not be a problem if `child2` is `List<Object>` on the Java side, or some abstract/base class instead of `Object`.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.